# after_validation processing in rails 3 model

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

just wondering if anyone knows a way to run after_validation logic depending on whether the :link attr is valid or not?

```
validates :link, :uri_check => { :schemes => [:ftp, :http, :https] } 

after_validation :initialize_dependents, :on => :create

def initialize_dependents 
  #post validation logic here
end
```

So instead of :on => :create, maybe...

```
after_validation :initialize_dependents, :if => link.valid?
```

The problem is I can only access the string and not the object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the `:if` like this:

```
:if => Proc.new { --code here-- }
```

or

```
:if => :my_method?

def my_method?
  --code here--
end
```

Comment: Hi Zabba, thanks for your reply.  Is there a way to access the outcome of the validation logic.  In my controller I can use @link.vaild?  How would I apply this without validating the (String) link in my model again?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  Just needed to create an Observer.

```
class LinkObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  after_validation(model)
   #logic here
  end

end
```